# Nest Swagger: How to defined a properties of an object with generic type?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, decorator

I'm doing a pagination common.
I want to define "order by" properties as a key in generic T

```
export class BasePagination<T> {
  @DtoNumber({ required: true })
  limit: number;
  @DtoNumber({ required: true })
  page: number;
  @ApiProperty()
  orderBy: keyOf T;
  @DtoEnum(SortOrder, { enum: [SortOrder.ascending, SortOrder.descending] })
  sort: SortOrder;
}
```

But somehow, in the UI swagger, I cannot see the order Query.

I tried custom another decorator

```
export const IsRecord = (validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) => {
  return function (object: unknown, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsRecord',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: {
        message: 'Wrong object format',
        ...validationOptions,
      },
      validator: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
        validate(value: unknown, _args: ValidationArguments) {
          if (!isObject(value)) return false;
          if (Object.keys(value).length === 0) return true;
          const keys = Object.keys(value);

          return keys.every((key) => {
            if (typeof key != 'string') return false;

            return Array.isArray(value[key]);
          });
        },
      },
    });
  };
```

But when app start, the @IsRecord have object = {}.
And it is not show in Swagger UI too.

Anyone help me to explain the reason why it does not display in swagger UI

Comment: Query params are strings by default, you can check this by sending a request and logging with `typeof`. In order to display `orderBy` in swagger you need to explicitly add `@ApiProperty({ type: String })`. However, to have correct types in your DTO object, you will need to add `@Transform()` decorators to each non string property and `transform: true` to ValidationPipe options. Otherwise your validators will not function properly and types will not reflect real underlying data types